# What is the Dump extension used for, and why is it so popular?

Tags: linqpad

To me, adding "Dump" to the end of an expression doesn't seem to do anything different, at least for seeing rows in a table.  Can you point me to an example of where it is handy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just working with an expression, there is no reason to call Dump—it's called automatically. But, in the language selection box, LINQPad allows allows the selection of Statements and Program. Once you select one of those, you don't get any Dump output unless you call it.

With Statements or Programs, you might want to call Dump on multiple times. In those cases, it is handy to pass the Description parameters so you can distinguish the output.

There are also other parameters you can use to shape the output, such as depth, which limits the substructure details.

Simple example (Language=C# Statements):

```
var integers = Enumerable.Range(1,10);

integers.Select(i => new { i, v = i * i}).Dump("Squares");
integers.Select(i => new { i, v = i * i * i}).Dump("Cubes");

var output = "λ is awesome";
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output)
    .Dump("UTF-8");
Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(output)
    .Dump("Windows-1252 (lossy)");
```

Comment: Interesting.  Why does the dump for Squares and Cubes add up the results at the bottom of the list?

Comment: That's just an automatic, value-added feature. Of course, the sum of a column only makes sense in some cases.